# Running SignalR self-host samples throws exception with latest mono dev branch

Tags: linux, mono, signalr

Using Mono on Linux, the sample Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Mono found at https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR seems to work using the stable release of mono but not with the latest development branch (3.99).  Anyone encounter this?  I get the following exception:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the
target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code
in (wrapper delegate-invoke)
<Module>:invoke_callvirt_CancellationTokenRegistration_CancellationToken&_Action`1<object>_object
(System.Threading.CancellationToken&,System.Action`1<object>,object): IL_004f:
castclass 0x00000007


  at
Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Infrastructure.CancellationTokenExtensions.SafeRegister
(CancellationToken cancellationToken, System.Action`1 callback, System.Object
state) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at
Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hosting.HostDependencyResolverExtensions.InitializeResolverDispose
(IDependencyResolver resolver, CancellationToken hostShutdownToken) [0x00000]
in <filename unknown>:0 
  at
Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hosting.HostDependencyResolverExtensions.InitializeHost
(IDependencyResolver resolver, System.String instanceName, CancellationToken
hostShutdownToken) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Owin.OwinExtensions.UseSignalRMiddleware[PersistentConnectionMiddleware]
(IAppBuilder builder, System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Owin.OwinExtensions.RunSignalR (IAppBuilder builder, System.Type
connectionType, Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.ConnectionConfiguration configuration)
[0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Owin.OwinExtensions.RunSignalR[RawConnection] (IAppBuilder builder,
Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.ConnectionConfiguration configuration) [0x00000] in
<filename unknown>:0 
  at Owin.OwinExtensions.RunSignalR[RawConnection] (IAppBuilder builder)
[0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.AspNet.SelfHost.Samples.Startup.<Configuration>b__0 (IAppBuilder
map) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Owin.MapExtensions.Map (IAppBuilder app, PathString pathMatch,
System.Action`1 configuration) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Owin.MapExtensions.Map (IAppBuilder app, System.String pathMatch,
System.Action`1 configuration) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.AspNet.SelfHost.Samples.Startup.Configuration (IAppBuilder app)
[0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke
(System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags
invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters,
System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags
invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters,
System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[]
parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader+<>c__DisplayClass12.<MakeDelegate>b__b
(IAppBuilder builder) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader+<>c__DisplayClass1.<LoadImplementation>b__0
(IAppBuilder builder) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Engine.HostingEngine.ResolveApp
(Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Engine.StartContext context) [0x00000] in <filename
unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Engine.HostingEngine.Start
(Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Engine.StartContext context) [0x00000] in <filename
unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Starter.DirectHostingStarter.Start
(Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.StartOptions options) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Starter.HostingStarter.Start
(Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.StartOptions options) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.StartImplementation (IServiceProvider
services, Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.StartOptions options) [0x00000] in <filename
unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.Start (Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.StartOptions
options) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.Start[Startup]
(Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.StartOptions options) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.Start[Startup] (System.String url) [0x00000]
in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.AspNet.SelfHost.Samples.Program.Main (System.String[] args)
[0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException:
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. --->
System.InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in (wrapper delegate-invoke)
<Module>:invoke_callvirt_CancellationTokenRegistration_CancellationToken&_Action`1<object>_object
(System.Threading.CancellationToken&,System.Action`1<object>,object): IL_004f:
castclass 0x00000007
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I eventually went with was to return the fallback register in ResolveRegisterDelegate() if IsRunningMono is true:

```
if (MonoUtility.IsRunningMono)
    return fallback;

try
{
    methodInfo = typeof(CancellationToken).GetMethod("InternalRegisterWithoutEC",
                                                             BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
                                                             binder: null,
                                                             types: new[] { typeof(Action<object>), typeof(object) },
                                                             modifiers: null);

}
catch
{
    // Swallow this exception. Being extra paranoid, we don't want anything to break in case this dirty
    // reflection hack fails for any reason
}
```

I noticed that this was happening in the earlier stable release of mono because the GetMethod("InternalRegisterWithoutEC") was returning null and did NOT return null with the latest dev branch of mono.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug in later versions of Mono. I reported this on Friday:  http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=29665

Comment: according to bugzilla, this has been fixed on May 6th, but after building this latest one and tried again, I still got exactly the same error.  Did anyone try and get it work?

Comment: Yes. See this comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29992634/issue-after-updating-to-mono-4-0-1-on-ubuntu?noredirect=1#comment48393715_29992634

Comment: @brian The fix has made it into the latest release source, however has yet to be packaged into a release. Scheduled release for this fix looks like 4.2.0. Until then either rollback to a 3.12.x version, or hold on until the release.

Answer (score 0):

That issue is already reported on SignalIR [repo](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-Server/issues/43). Try pulling the latest version of the dev branch, ASP.NET team have commented out the code throwing that exception as a workaround for now.

Comment: I was working out of the SignalR repo [here](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR), not the asp.net vNext stuff, which is currently and unfortunately not an option for me.