# Issue after updating to mono 4.0.1 on Ubuntu

Tags: asp.net, ubuntu, mono, signalr, self-hosting

I just upgraded to the *just released* Mono version **4.0.1** on my ubuntu machines. The previous installed version of mono was 3.2.7 (if I remember correctly).

Now the issue:

My first issue is regarding SignalR and self-hosting. I have a .NET 4.5.1 console application in which I self host NancyFx, Web Api and SignalR using OWIN. When running on mono 3.2.7 there was no issues to my knowledge but when I try to start the application on mono 4.0.1 I get the following stack trace:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in (wrapper delegate-invoke) <Module>:invoke_callvirt_CancellationTokenRegistration_CancellationToken&_Action`1<object>_object (System.Threading.CancellationToken&,System.Action`1<object>,object): IL_0057: castclass 0x00000007

  at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Infrastructure.CancellationTokenExtensions.SafeRegister (CancellationToken cancellationToken, System.Action`1 callback, System.Object state) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hosting.HostDependencyResolverExtensions.InitializeResolverDispose (IDependencyResolver resolver, CancellationToken hostShutdownToken) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hosting.HostDependencyResolverExtensions.InitializeHost (IDependencyResolver resolver, System.String instanceName, CancellationToken hostShutdownToken) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Owin.OwinExtensions.UseSignalRMiddleware[HubDispatcherMiddleware] (IAppBuilder builder, System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Owin.OwinExtensions.RunSignalR (IAppBuilder builder, Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.HubConfiguration configuration) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Owin.OwinExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass1.<MapSignalR>b__0 (IAppBuilder subApp) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Owin.MapExtensions.Map (IAppBuilder app, PathString pathMatch, System.Action`1 configuration) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Owin.MapExtensions.Map (IAppBuilder app, System.String pathMatch, System.Action`1 configuration) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Owin.OwinExtensions.MapSignalR (IAppBuilder builder, System.String path, Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.HubConfiguration configuration) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Owin.OwinExtensions.MapSignalR (IAppBuilder builder, Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.HubConfiguration configuration) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Owin.OwinExtensions.MapSignalR (IAppBuilder builder) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I have no clue to what this error could mean and I'm greatful for all assistance. I'm using Microsoft ASP.NET SignalR Self Host package version 2.2.0.

And as a side note, I've compiled all my assemblies on the new mono version.

Kind regards,
Simon

Comment: I saw it in the Asp.Net vNext - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28288136/running-signalr-self-host-samples-throws-exception-with-latest-mono-dev-branch and here https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-Server/issues/93. I wonder if this is a bug in mono...

Comment: I filed an issue against Mono - https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=29665

Comment: @Pawel thanks, had the same issue but everything works with mono master

Comment: @Heather - yes, looks like it was fixed 3 days ago - https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=29665#c5

Answer (score 3):

This turned out to be a Mono issue which was recently fixed: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=29665