# What is changed about reflection in mono 4.x? (compatibility with mono 3.x)

Tags: c#, .net, mono

My exception with mono 4:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in (wrapper delegate-invoke) <Module>:invoke_callvirt_CancellationTokenRegistration_CancellationToken&_Action`1<object>_object (System.Threading.CancellationToken&,System.Action`1<object>,object): IL_0057: castclass 0x00000007
```

more details available here: https://github.com/Anthilla/Antd/issues/8

Everything builds fine with mono `3.2.x, 3.12.1 and other 3.x` but starting from `4.0.0-beta` (`4.0.1`, `4.0.1.28`) I'm getting this strange exception.

So I wonder if there there is no IL compatibility and so then how it possible to use nuget? What is changed about reflection in 4.x?

same issue is here: [Issue after updating to mono 4.0.1 on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29992634/issue-after-updating-to-mono-4-0-1-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related this commit: https://github.com/mono/mono/commit/ae495e8bd485f48ecdb7e53d7e98771220f31997

and this bug: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=29665

But build `4.0.1.28` is from branch `4.0.0` and not from master so there is no this fix there and it will be fixed in `4.1` // credits for this answer goes 
to David Karlas from mono gitter

everything work well with mono from `master`

Comment: One correct. The next release of Mono should be 4.2 according to its developer mailing list. :)

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/4.0.0/

- **Adoption of Microsoft’s open source code**
- C# 6.0
- Floating point optimizations
- We dropped support for the 2.0, 3.5 and 4.0 assemblies
- Updated IKVM
- Lighter Debugger overhead
- Basic PowerPC64 LE support

(I added the bold)

They changed many classes from their ("original" Mono) implementations to the Microsoft ones (http://referencesource.microsoft.com), so many "hacks" that were present to be compatible with Mono are now non-functional, because the CLR libraries used are Microsoft ones, and they probably introduced new bugs, because they even changed some code in the reference source to make it compatible. It was a "stop the train, change the world" version.